# REST is recognized by wrong (partially right) class, how to prevent from this?

Tags: java, rest, web, jboss

I've got

`@Path("web-filters/wizard/{type}/{id}/clone")` annotation on one class

and

`@Path("web-filters/wizard/filters")` annotation on the other class.

`filters` can be passed as `type` path param.

And my problem is that REST i.e. `host-and-etc/web-filters/wizard/filters/123/clone` tries to found a path in the second class, co I've got 404. Is there an option to prevent from this?

I can move RESTs from first to second resource, but that is not what I want to do, at least I wish I can do it smarter.

Comment: Can you provide some more details so that people will help you.

Comment: I think that is enough. I've got two classes with partially same paths and when I use url `web-filters/wizard/filters/123/clone` it is not recognized by first class, cause second class is asked (I think so, due to partially same address) first and it returns 404.

Comment: Maybe you can try using @Path annotation on methods not classes. Then using your method signatures you can parse path params. This link may help. https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Using__Path_and__GET___POST__etc..html

Comment: The path web-filters/wizard/filters creates ambiguity while invocation, it is recommended to have different path so that one can easily distinguish.